# Could anyone help me with these two SQL queries on my Items table?

Tags: sql, databricks-community-edition

I made a SQL project for myself to learn.

I am trying to answer these two questions:

1. How many total items were sold between 1970 and 2000?
2. What state in the US had the most items sold overall?

I am using the databricks community edition. I am trying to teach myself how to use a big data tool. I uploaded a csv file from a dataset website. I was able to generate the table just fine. I even made a couple of SQL queries that I was able to write on my own and got results.

I am having issues with these last two queries. Below is the table information, and my query for the 1st question.

Table name: Items

Columns:

```
datetime (Date format is 10/10/1972 19:00)
City
state
country
item
```

My effort for the first question (How many total items were sold between 1970 and 2000?) that isn't working and gets errors:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Items]
WHERE Date BETWEEN '01-01-1970' AND '12-31-2000`
```

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: mismatched input '[' expecting
> {, ';'}(line 2, pos 5) == SQL == SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [items]
> -----^^^ WHERE Date BETWEEN '01-01-1970' AND '12-31-2000`

What am I doing wrong? Also, I am not sure how to even begin the second question SQL query.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '[' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 2, pos 5)

== SQL ==
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [items]
-----^^^
WHERE Date BETWEEN '01-01-1970' AND '12-31-2000`

Comment: WHERE datetime BETWEEN '01-01-1970' AND '12-31-2000`

Comment: I changed it to datetime BETWEEN.... and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your where statement needs to look for the actual column name, and if that column name is a reserved word, like 'Date' it needs to be dotted like [Items].[Date]

Comment: I tried this and it didn't return anything. 


SELECT COUNT(datetime), datetime FROM UFO_Sightings_csv
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "'
GROUP BY datetime ORDER BY COUNT(datetime) DESC;

Comment: Is your column named [Date] or [datetime]? Either way you should rename it to something that is not a SQL reserved word. If you cannot rename your column, you probably have to reference it with the table name first, like the example in my answer.

Comment: The column name is datetime. And how do I rename it? Sorry, I am also learning SQL.

Comment: I would use ALTER TABLE to add the new column, update it to the old value then drop the original column. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Comment: Ok I am lost now. lol

Comment: I did this query, and it returned things, but it is showing dates earlier than 1970 and later than 2000---- I need a total number for all items for that date range, not rows of numbers and dates which is what this query returned.....SELECT COUNT(*), datetime FROM Items
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '01-01-1970' AND '12-31-2000'
GROUP BY datetime ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;